# Интервалы Datetime и TimeSpan больше 24 часов в c#

Tags: c#, datetime

Есть таблица, в ней хранятся данные об отработанных часах.

В конце в textBox нужен итог, но при суммировании получается количество часов не больше 24, как сделать что бы при суммировании часов результат был больше 24 часов, например 108:10 (108 часов 10 минут).

Comment: [TotalHours](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timespan.totalhours(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 3):

Складывайте timespan'ы, потом смотрите в TotalHours общее количество часов:

```
TimeSpan interval1 = TimeSpan.FromHours(10);
TimeSpan interval2 = TimeSpan.FromHours(20);
TimeSpan total = interval1 + interval2;
Console.WriteLine(total.TotalHours);
```

Выведет 10 + 20 = 30 часов.